# ¿Como retorno de un método de tipo List<T>?

Tags: c#, lista

Tengo la clase:

```
public class OrderViewModelResponse
{

    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }
    public string SalesRepresentativeAssigned { get; set; }
}
```

Y tengo otro método que hará debe retornar la lista de todos las órdenes de la tabla `Orders`.

```
public class OrdersData : BaseDataAccess, IOrdersData
{
    public List<OrderViewModelResponse> GetAllOrders()
    {
        var codigoDeOrdenes= Context.Orders.Select(o => o.idOrder).ToList();
       return  ??;
    }
}
```

Soy principiante en C#, requiero un poco de ayuda.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tu método debería quedar como el siguiente ya que debes retornar todos los atributos de tu modelo `OrderViewModelResponse`:

```
public class OrdersData : BaseDataAccess, IOrdersData
{
    public List<OrderViewModelResponse> GetAllOrders()
    {
        return (from p in Context.Orders select new OrderViewModelResponse {
                    OrderId = p.OrderId,
                    CreatedDate = p.CreatedDate
                    Total = p.Total,
                    SalesRepresentativeAssigned = p.SalesRepresentativeAssigned
                    }).ToList();
    }
}
```